# Trigger api call on setting the default value of MUI Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state, onchange

**In Short : Execute the onChange event when default value is set in Material-UI Select Component.**

When you will run this react component, you will find a Material UI Select Component  with a defaut selected option as 10 which is being set using useState hook.How to make an API call at the same time when the default value is being set.
The onChange props will only execute when we change the dropdown menu item.If we are loading our page with some Select Component and setting some default menu item, then how can we make an API call and get some Data.

**Use the CodeSand Box link.** The alert message does not executes even though the menu-item/ option in the Select is getting changed from empty string to 10.

Assume that the default value is coming from some API call.

```
export default function SelectVariants() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("10");

   
  
  
  //This should execute by default or on Page Load
  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
    alert("Run on load"); // Can be an API Call on the Page load And also on Subsequent onChange Events
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-standard-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-standard"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
        >
      <MenuItem value={""}>None</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Pen Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-srbyi2?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 1):

Following this requirement:

> Set a default value on the `Select` which is coming from an API call
> (API-1) -> then using the same default value, trigger another API call
> (API-2) -> then at every `onChange` of `Select` menu, also make API call
> (API-2) only.

```
const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  api1().then((defaultValue) => {
    setAge(defaultValue);
    api2(defaultValue);
  });
}, []);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setAge(event.target.value);
  api2(event.target.value);
};
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hh39e3?file=/demo.js)

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, that will make an API call on the page load,but useEffect will be called  every time when "age" will change. But this will make useEffect trigger every time I change my "age".  For next "age" change , I want to trigger the onChange from the <Select>. Only for the default value i want to use the useEffect. @user4980215

Comment: @indrasentraining Then you can omit the age dependency and it will be called once. Sorry, I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Get default value from API -> show Select -> user select -> get another data from API based on the selected value?

Comment: Requirement is this : Set a default value on the Select which is coming from an API call  (API-1)  >>  then using the same default value, trigger another API call   (API-2) >> then at every onChange of Select menu, also make  API call (API-2) only . I hope you get this - @user4980215

Comment: Adding one more coment to make it more clear. The user selects only for the second time. For the first time the value coming from API will be selected on the Select and that should trigger the API call (API-2). And then the subsequent change of options also triggers API call (API-2). @user4980215